# Explode Array Element into a unique column

Tags: pyspark

I'm new to Pyspark and trying to solve an ETL step.

I have the following schema below. I would like to take the variable that is inside the array and transform it into a column, but when doing this with *explode* I create duplicate rows because there are positions [0], [1], and [2] inside the element.

My goal is to transform what is inside *variable* into a new column taking everything that is in the element (separating by comma what was in each element) and transforming it into a string.

```
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- info: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- variable: string (nullable = true)
```

Output:

| id | new column |
| --- | --- |
| 123435e5x-9a9z | A, B, D |
| 555585a4Z-0B1Y | A |

Thank you for the help

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.concat_ws.html

Comment: Thank you! already taking a look

Comment: can you show example of input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by David Markovitz you can use the concat_ws function as below:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
(df.withColumn('new column', F.concat_ws(', ', F.col('info'))
```

Comment: I guess that 'info' column (as it is an array) has its own separator, and in this case you don't need to mention the separator on concat_ws function, it will only extract information from an array and transform it in a string

Comment: You're correct, separator must be informed!